# sorting and merge untidy data frame with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have multiple untidy data frames with only one column (more than 500 csv files)and all of them are in a same directory

all of them in one column and with out row numbers
[untidy csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW3Nb.png)

how can I sort rows and columns and merge them in one csv file?
I want to tidy my csv files and merge them like this enter image description here

[merged csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXaZa.png)

Comment: You must provide your input as **text**, images of data are not acceptable

Comment: can you please provide more information on the input DataFrame? I don't see the values that are in the "merged csv" in the "untidy csv" - can you please provide in table format?

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) your string, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['NAME nokia1000', 'MAKE nokia', 'PRICE 509', 'COLOR blue']})

out = (df['col']
    .str.split(n=1, expand=True)
    .assign(index=lambda d: d[0].eq('NAME').cumsum().sub(1))
    .pivot(index='index', columns=0, values=1)
    .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
  COLOR   MAKE       NAME PRICE
0  blue  nokia  nokia1000   509
```